# Windows forms adding the same binding second time causes argument exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics

I bind "Enabled" property of button to datasource member. I use `Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButton` control and its method `DataBindings.Add( System.Windows.Forms.Binding )`. The button is on dialog form. When I open dialog for the first time binding is added ok. After I close dialog and open it second time I get exception in `System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)`, message says that "Enabled" property of button is read-only. How to solve this?

Dialog opening code is like this:

```
using (PickItemDialog dialog = new PickItemDialog())
{
    dialog.ViewModel = new PickItemViewModel();
    dialog.ViewModel.Items = new BindingList<T>(records.ToList());
    dialog.ViewModel.Title = title;
    dialog.ViewModel.Notification = notification;
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        return (DataItem)dialog.ViewModel.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: Show the code which opens the dailog.

Comment: Problem occurs only the second time I try to open the dialog.

Comment: Sounds like typical Infragistics lossage.  Use the vendor's support channels to find help, their support staff doesn't answer questions here.

Comment: The Enabled property is defined on Control. Are you saying you're getting different behavior when using a WinForms Button than when using the IG Button? If so enable first chance exceptions (i.e. check Debug->Exceptions->Common Language Runtime Exceptions) and post the callstack of the error.